# Python TCP client doesn't recv data after inactivity

Tags: sockets, tcp, client-server

I created an application in Python that connect to a Server and retrive message from it.

All works fine, but after a while the client stop retriving data from server without any error.

It still stuck at self.sock.recv
I tried with setblocking but seem that doesn't work (should be blocking by default right?)

That is my code:

```
[...]
try:
                print "Awaiting new data..."
                data = self.sock.recv(5)
                print "\n### " + data
                if data:
                    data = data.decode('utf-8')
                    size = data[:4].lstrip("0")
                    data = data + self.sock.recv(int(size))
                    print data
                else:
                    raise socket.error(errno.ENETUNREACH,"Network is unreachable")
                    #print "Size: "+str(size)
                self.emit(self.signal, data)
            except socket.error, (value,message):
                print "# FAIL #: " + message
                self.RUNNING = False
time.sleep(0.5)
[...]
```

Last messages in console (client) are:

```
   ### 0015< Message here!!
   Awaiting data...
```

Last message in console (SERVER) are:

```
2014-07-26 16:21:34,290 INFO     >>> Sending to client
2014-07-26 16:21:34,291 INFO     Message: Hello
2014-07-26 16:21:34,291 INFO     7
2014-07-26 16:21:34,291 INFO     Queued
2014-07-26 16:21:34,292 INFO     # SUCCESS #: 0005<Hello
2014-07-26 16:21:34,292 INFO     Pending new status...
```

No more output, no error, nothing... but server still sending (with success) message to client.

Any suggestion how to fix that issue?

**EDIT:**
After some test I found that the issue appear only when the server is in an other computer.
If client and server are in the same computer it works good.
What could be the cause of that?

Comment: How do you know that the server is still sending data? Is it sending data forever?

Comment: because the server do the socks.send(message) without raising error, so I assume the message is sent to client

Comment: And how did you make sure that the server is actually sending forever? Log every send to the console to make sure.

Comment: I'm logging every action of client and of server, I updated the question with the logs of server, that in case of error (i.e. Client closed) it appear with ## FAIL ## instead of SUCCESS

Comment: This sounds something like the behavior you might see if there was a temporary connectivity outage between the client and the server.  To confirm (or deny) that as a possible issue, you could try running the server and the client on the same computer and see if the problem goes away in that case.

Comment: It's blocking without failing because there is no data to receive.  Your protocol may be out-of-sync.  Also note that a blocking `recv(5)` can return 1-5 bytes.  Check the return value.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I'm trying it in the same machine, and it is working at the moment, if it will work also after a few hours how can I fix it to works also in remote server?

@MarkTolonen The server print the result of `recv(5)` at every step. the problem is that it never go to print but still on recv